# Which java class triggers natural mob spawns?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to find in the code which class or classes trigger mob spawns. For example if I wanted to change the Y at which slimes spawn or allow a custom mob like an elephant spawn on the Savannah biome.

Intent is to do this for a forge mod, but I assume the answer is standard for minecraft?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get any luck here, there's a decent amount of minecraft Q&A here too: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

For mod-added entities, `EntityRegistry.addSpawn(...)` is used to register which biomes the entity will spawn in using the existing per-biome spawn rules.

For slimes, the class EntitySlime controls what Y heights it is allowed to spawn at, see the `getCanSpawnHere()` method. However, you cannot modify this class. In order to override what heights are valid, you would need to subscribe to the `LivingSpawnEvent` (there are three subclasses, you would want to subscribe to one of the three) and set the result to `Result.ALLOW` to force the entity to spawn regardless of its usual spawn checks (conversely, `Result.DENY` to prevent it).

Comment: This seems to be moved in 1.16 (there is no `EntityRegistry`)