# Modify mob spawn rates in a Forge Minecraft mod (1.16)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm new to modding Minecraft and I was wondering how to change mob spawn rates. Let's say we want to spawn lots of Endermen for example.

So far I've found the code that seems to sets the spawn frequency in `net.minecraft.world.biome` `DefaultBiomeFeatures.java`:

```
public static void withHostileMobs(MobSpawnInfo.Builder builder) {
   ...
   builder.withSpawner(EntityClassification.MONSTER, new MobSpawnInfo.Spawners(EntityType.ENDERMAN, 10, 1, 4));
   ...
}
```

meaning Endermen spawn in most biomes, albeit rarely (10 is the weight, creepers and spiders have 100).

I know this `DefaultBiome` is then used by `BiomeMaker.java` to `makeGiantTaigaBiome`, `makeBirchForestBiome` etc. **My conclusion is that I need to change the biomes to change spawn rates.**

I can access the biomes using either `BiomeRegistry` or `ForgeRegistries.BIOMES`. I see 2 approaches here:

1. **Replace the map of biomes completely.** Sadly its `register` method is `private` so I cannot add new biomes to replace the existing ones. I also read [here](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/60053-impossible-to-override-vanilla-biomes/) that removing them is apparently not possible.
2. **Modify the existing map of biomes.** This would use `biome.withMobSpawnSettings(MobSpawnInfo mobSpawnSettings)` to modify the biome in-place. But the `MobSpawnInfo`  class *once again does not have any public setters*, so I don't see how I can get a modified `MobSpawnInfo` without re-creating the entire `MobSpawnInfo` object by hand.

---

Most solutions online ([1](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/modification-development/1436796-how-do-you-change-spawn-rates?comment=2), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45473852/2111778)) seem to suggest the following which sadly do no longer work in the current 1.16.4:

```
ModLoader.addSpawn(YOURENTITY.class, 25, 1, 3);
```

```
EntityRegistry.addSpawn(...)
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to modify the existing Minecraft package using Mixins -- that is called *coremodding* and frowned upon for various reasons. The correct approach for 1.16 is to *subscribe* to a BiomeLoadingEvent and then monkey-patch all biomes after they have been loaded:

---

**1.16**

```java
@Mod("example")
public class ExampleMod
{
    public ExampleMod() {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.HIGH)
    public void onBiomeLoadingEvent(BiomeLoadingEvent event) {
        List<MobSpawnInfo.Spawners> spawns = 
            event.getSpawns().getSpawner(EntityClassification.MONSTER);

        // Remove existing Enderman spawn information
        spawns.removeIf(e -> e.type == EntityType.ENDERMAN);

        // Make Enderman spawns more frequent and add Blaze spawns in all biomes
        spawns.add(new MobSpawnInfo.Spawners(EntityType.BLAZE, 200, 1, 4));
        spawns.add(new MobSpawnInfo.Spawners(EntityType.ENDERMAN, 200, 1, 4));
    }
}
```

---

**1.15 (might also work in 1.14, 1.13, 1.12, ...)**

```java
@Mod("example")
public class ExampleMod
{
    public ExampleMod() {
        ForgeRegistries.BIOMES.forEach(biome -> {
            List<Biome.SpawnListEntry> spawns = biome.getSpawns(EntityClassification.MONSTER);
            spawns.removeIf(e -> e.entityType == EntityType.ENDERMAN);
            spawns.add(new Biome.SpawnListEntry(EntityType.BLAZE, 200, 1, 4));
            spawns.add(new Biome.SpawnListEntry(EntityType.ENDERMAN, 200, 1, 4));
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: Note that the [InControl](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/in-control) can be used to achieve a similar effect, requiring no coding.

Comment: It Needs to be "**public static void onBiomeLoadingEvent**" in your example is missing the "**static**" otherwise it wont execute at all. I Hope it help people that are confused why it wont spawn custom mobs but the code dont throw errors .